# DataGridView shows columns that were set to non-visible

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have 3 datagridviews, and each of them has a separate binding source. All three binding sources however get data from the same datatable.

```
        bindingSource1.DataSource = mytable;
        bindingSource2.DataSource = mytable;
        bindingSource3.DataSource = mytable;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = bindingSource2;
        dataGridView3.DataSource = bindingSource3;
```

I control what the user sees with the following logic: Show 10 first columns on the first grid, the next 10 on the second, and the next 10 on the third.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mytable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].Visible = i < 10;
            dataGridView2.Columns[i].Visible = (i >= 10 && i < 20);
            dataGridView3.Columns[i].Visible = (i >= 20 && i < 30);
        }
```

This works fine when I have many columns in the datatable.

**Problem** If I have less than 10 columns in my datatable, normally they should only be shown in the first datagridview. This does happen, but also the **first** column of the datatable is always shown in datagrid 2 and 3. I have stepped through my loop to see whether a condition is wrong, and I found it to be correct. Therefore, I am pretty sure it must be one of the events that follow  this. I have two events registed for my grids that could be the cuplrits: **RowPostPaint** and **CellPainting**. I commented out everything that I was doing in these events and still get this problem. I also have some others, like DataError, CellValueChanged(empty inside), Scroll etc, but I think they are irrelevant.

So I am wondering whether there is another event which I haven't registered, which could be doing this by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this behavior because of a default behavior that happens when binding the data source. To fix, handle each `DataGridView.DataBindingComplete` event. We will use the same event handler for each:

```
dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += DataGridView_DataBindingComplete;
dataGridView2.DataBindingComplete += DataGridView_DataBindingComplete;
dataGridView3.DataBindingComplete += DataGridView_DataBindingComplete;
```

In that event handler, we will set the visible columns as before.  But we will also set the row headers' visibility as well as scroll bars - in case no columns are visible.

```
private void DataGridView_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView view = sender as DataGridView;
    bool anyVisible = false;
    int max = 0, min = 0;

    if (view == this.dataGridView1)
    {
        min = 0;
        max = 10;
    }
    else if (view == this.dataGridView2)
    {
        min = 10;
        max = 20;
    }
    else if (view == this.dataGridView3)
    {
        min = 20;
        max = 30;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < this.table.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        view.Columns[i].Visible = i >= min && i < max;
        anyVisible = anyVisible || view.Columns[i].Visible;
    }

    view.RowHeadersVisible = anyVisible;
    view.ScrollBars = anyVisible ? ScrollBars.Both : ScrollBars.None;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great solution.